# Ruby on Rails: macOS is required An unsatisfied requirement failed this build

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, heroku, homebrew

I'm trying to deploy my app with Heroku, but when I type in the terminal

```
brew install heroku
```

I get an error

```
heroku: macOS is required.
Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.
```

I've tried many other commands such as

```
brew install heroku-toolbelt
```

But I still get the same error. My Mac currently OS Sierra version 10.12.5

When I ran

```
brew doctor
```

I get

```
setting LD_* vars can break dynamic linking.
Set variables:
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH: ~/.c9/local/lib
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: This could be an issue with the [Heroku gem](https://github.com/heroku/legacy-cli).

Comment: If it is, how would I fix it?

Comment: The [Homebrew recipe](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/heroku.rb) doesn't look that complicated, and for what it's worth, `brew install heroku` worked for me on 10.12, so it's not clear what's wrong. I'm curious if anyone else has encountered the problem.

Comment: This is interesting. I haven't used the local heroku myself for a while (I have automatic deploys setup from my CI server/github on all my projects). I'll star it and if I have time tonight when I'm in front of my mac I'l look for you.

My initial thought is to `brew uninstall heroku heroku-toolbelt` and try reinstalling the tool belt.

Comment: Somehow I heard home-brew doesn't work on macOS Sierra, is there anyway I can solve that issue?

Comment: Homebrew works fine on Sierra, but do you mean just this one recipe?

Comment: why does this have cloud9-ide tag?

Comment: I'm sorry, what is a "recipe"? Pretty new to the to this stuff. I've tried to look this problem up online without success and I see that a lot of people have a problem with Home-brew working on Sierra. I attempted using Heroku a week ago with out this problem which was before I upgrade to Sierra

Comment: @bockdavidson Homebrew (`brew`) calls the scripts for installing packages "recipes", where `brew install heroku` means "install using the `heroku` recipe".

Comment: Yes, I just need to install the heroku recipe

Comment: I am still having problems, no progression

Comment: @tadman It calls them "formulae" to be precise.